# |= (or_eq) order of evaluation in C++

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, operator-precedence

I was trying to find the answer to the following question, but was unsuccessful.
I have the expression involving bit AND and bit OR (everything unsigned long):

```
A |= B & C
```

What is the order of evaluation in C++?
Is it `A = A | (B & C)` or `A = (A | B) & C`? Or it depends on the compiler version?
Thanks.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: You're "expanding"  too soon. There are two possible interpretations when there are two binary operators - `(A |= B) & C` and `A |= (B & C)`.

Comment: I'm curious to know, why couldn't you find the documentation for operator precedence?  Do you just not know of the word "precedence"?  Even searching for "order of evaluation", which appears in your question, turns up lots of good info for me.

Comment: Side note: "order of evaluation" and "precedence" are different things. It's easy to get lost if you confuse them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the compound assignment operators (`op=`), the expression `E1 op= E2` becomes `E1 = E1 op E2`<sup>[1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.ass#6)</sup>.  That means for your code that `E1` is `A` and `E2` is `B & C` so the result would be

```
A = A | (B & C)
```